Assignment problem over multiple time steps
I have a problem connected to a set of technicians serving multiple jobs. Every job is characterised by a single time instant which could be 1, 2, 3, … , T when the job needs to be served, and also a location where the job needs to be served.
Each technician would cover a job in time slot 1 , then a job in time slot 2, and so on in a sequential manner.
The objective is to maximize jobs served while minimising total distance.
One approach I could think is that between successive time slots, one could consider an assignment problem between technicians (at their current locations) and jobs for the next time slot.
Is it possible to prove that this approach while giving optimum at each time step, also gives the global optimum ? If not, would this be a good heuristic ?
Would you be able suggest any alternative approaches to solving this problem, especially ones amenable to additional constraints ?

Just to clarify the time slots are time instants, akin to sequencing and not time windows.

Are you assuming that any technician can cover any job and then travel any distance within one time step?

As of now, yes. Also regarding the criterion of maximising number of jobs served: if at any time step the number of jobs allotted that time step exceeds number of technicians, then the difference number cannot be served. So I think in the current formulation, the only optimization required is for total distance.

You need to be a bit careful with the service part. In the case you described, a constraint that all customers must be served would make the problem infeasible. On the other hand, if you just minimize distance with no requirement that any particular customer be served, the solution may wind up being the technicians sitting around chatting with each other (zero distance). So you might want to require that, in each time period, the number of customers served must be the smaller of the number of customers available in that period and the number of technicians.

If the number of customers in a single period can exceed the number of technicians, then the approach of optimizing each time period individually may not yield an optimal solution. Take the simple case of one technician, two time periods, two customers (A and B) in period 1 and one customer (C) in period 2. The arc lengths are 1 from start to A, 2 from start to B, 20 from A to C and 3 from B to C. The optimal solution with respect to distance is start -> B -> C (total distance 5), but optimizing the first step sends the tech to A, then in the second step to C with total distance 21.

If number of customers = number of technicians at each time step, then would approach of optimising each time period individually give the global minimum ?

Yes, because at the start of each time step other than the first or last there will be exactly one tech at each node of the previous time step. So, assuming all techs are interchangeable, the state at the start of a time step does not depend on the solution of earlier time steps.

Assignment from time t to t+1 would need to know which customers you served at time t, and which ones you didn't. You can formulate this as a simple flow problem instead and solve optimally using minimum cost graph. You will need

A source node and each unit of flow coming out of it will be equal to vehicle leasing cost. One arc per customer (at all levels) will be connected from source node (thus, a vehicle can start at any time).
Connect each customer in level t to each customer in level t+1 indicating possible connections, and the cost being the travel cost.
Represent each customer as two nodes (arrival and departure) nodes. The arc connecting these will have a flow upper/lower bound of 1.
And a sink node at the end from all customers (indicating vehicle lease complete).

Once you have a solution, you can extract the vehicle routes by tracing and extracting flows from source to sink node.

Thanks.The flow problem is new to me. I understand for each edge, the capacity, and the cost per unit of flow along this edge are given.In this case, capacity for all edges should be one ? And cost per unit of flow for each edge should be the travel distance ?

What do you mean by each unit of flow coming out of source will be equal to vehicle leasing cost - is this simply the distance from source to corresponding node ? Why split each customer as two nodes, and what do flow upper lower bounds for an edge mean ?

Yes, on arcs connecting one location to next, Cost will be per unit will be travel cost (covert distance to cost to keep all consistent). On the arcs connecting from source to all customers, it indicates you are using a new vehicle. So, this cost will be whatever you want to keep (a higher value that travel cost) to make sure number of vehicles used is minimum. Customer is split into two nodes to be able to put a constraint of "1" unit of flow on (thus, ensuring one and exactly one vehicle is serving each customer).

You can use OR Tools for solving this. See https://developers.google.com/optimization/flow/mincostflow

Presumably you have a supply limit (equal to the number of techs) on the source node. How do you handle demand constraints? If you require each customer node to be visited, the model may be infeasible (per OP's comment about possibly having too many customers in a single period). If you do not require nodes to be serviced, the optimal solution may be for all techs to make a beeline from the supply node to the demand node, bypassing customer nodes. Also, the one unit flow limit on customer nodes works only if arc lengths satisfy the triangle inequality.

Thanks for your insights, @prubin. One way to handle the point you noted is. Solve this as a series of problems. Step 1: Change the lower bound on the arc related to each job as zero, so that the option of not serving the job is also there. Step 2: Cost of each travel arc = - (minus) 100000 + Travel Cost. 100000 reward for serving each customer. No negative cycles, so min cost should be ok.  Step 3: For each "given number of technicians", find the maximum jobs you can cover using min cost. In other words, technician count will be an input and we loop over it. Thoughts?

Seems reasonable, but I would want to confirm it on a test problem to be sure. As stated, the problem is inherently bicriterion, so OP would need to clarify priorities.

Thanks @prubin. Arun, please post a query here if you need more details to work out the final solution.

I only see an option to input cost and capacity for edges in ORTools. How do I input flow bounds ? How to convert distances to costs ? Since number of vehicles is fixed, how do I assign costs and capacities to arcs connecting source node to customers? And I assume supply for source node will be = number of vehicles, and for sink = - (minus) number of vehicles, and zero for all others ?

Since there is no lower bound (see my updated comment above from yesterday), you are only dealing with upper bound, which is capacity. Yes, for the supply and demand comment.

Thanks. please clarify if each of my following statements are correct …, the capacity for all edges will be one. And the cost  for all edges can be -100000 + travel distance corresponding to the arc. This would be the case for edges connecting source to a time step , as well as time step to another time step ? What about for the cost for the edge connecting customer node that is split to two ? And how do I incorporate 100000 reward for serving each customer in the OR tools formulation ?

@prubin Arvind, if i have that the number of customers at every time step, is greater than or equal to number of agents, then i can add edges between every pair of requests with consecutive time steps. The number of unserved customers is simply the sum of difference between number of requests and number of agents across all time steps. I do not understand how to handle the case when number of requests at any time step is less than number of agents - would need a way to make extra agents wait and also make them available for requests after skipping time steps. Any ideas ?

If you have more agents than customers at time step $t,$ you can allow agents to flow from a customer at time $t-1$ directly to a customer at time $t+1$ or later. This amounts to adding arcs from nodes in any time step to nodes in time steps beyond the next one. If, say, you have excess agents at times $t$ through $t+k$ but not at $t+k+1$ you could add arcs from nodes at time $t-1$ to nodes all times $t$ through $t+k+1$ but not beyond that, since you know you will want all agents serving customers at time $t+k+1.$

@prubin Also, how do i ensure that each customer is served by no more than one agent (i.e. each node other than source/sink can have no more than one incoming and one outgoing edge) ? Specifically, i am current using the google OR tools formulation developers.google.com/optimization/flow/mincostflow and there does not seem like there is an option to control this.

i'm setting demands for all internal nodes as zero, that of source and sink as +/- number of agents. Capacity=1 for all edges.

just checked that @ArvindKumar addressed this earlier, by using splitting each node to two, with an edge with capacity=1 joining the two.
However, the need for the below two steps is still not clear to me. Why not just have edge costs = distances between the customers :?  [[Step 2: Cost of each travel arc = - (minus) 100000 + Travel Cost. 100000 reward for serving each customer. No negative cycles, so min cost should be ok. Step 3: For each "given number of technicians", find the maximum jobs you can cover using min cost. In other words, technician count will be an input and we loop over it]]

If edges are being constructed only between successive time slots' customers, (and not say have edges from source to all customers), shouldn't that automatically ensure that the number of customers served is maximised ?
